# Codeigniter Ajax record is saved but is not display luvr

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I'm fighting with ajax process of my codeigniter application.

I build the save process of data in db submitted by a form. Now I want, with ajax that the form show live the data submitted.

I've build search and pagination process, and all things works. But not the live output when submitted a data in form.

This is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

  function costumer_cells(data)
    {

      return '<tr>'+
              '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="' + data.id_anagrafica + '" name="id_anagrafica" /></td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.nome +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.cognome +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.telefono +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.email +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.cf +'</ td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.data_nascita +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.comune +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.tipo_attivita +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.note_anagrafica +'</td>'+
              '<td>'+ data.note_tipo_attivita +'</td>'+
              '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                  '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-id_anagrafica="'+ data.id_anagrafica +'" data-nome="'+data.nome+'" data-cognome="'+data.cognome+'" data-telefono="'+data.telefono+'" data-email="'+data.email+'" data-cf="'+data.cf+'" data-nascita="'+data.data_nascita+'" data-comune="'+data.comune+'"data-tipo_attivita="'+data.tipo_attivita+'" data-note_anagrafica="'+data.note_anagrafica+'" data-note_tipo_attivita="'+data.note_tipo_attivita+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                  '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-id_anagrafica="'+data.id_anagrafica+'">Delete</a>'+
              '</td>'+
              '</tr>';

    }

    function read() {
        return {
          nome: $('#nome').val(),
          cognome: $('#cognome').val(),
          telefono: $('#telefono').val(),
          email: $('#email').val(),
          cf: $('#cf').val(),
          data_nascita: $('#data_nascita').val(),
          comune: $('#comune').val(),
          tipo_attivita: $('#tipo_attivita').val(),
          note_anagrafica: $('#note_anagrafica').val(),
          note_tipo_attivita: $('#note_tipo_attivita').val(),
        }
      }

  function save(data){
    $('[name="nome"]').val(data.nome);
    $('[name="cognome"]').val(data.cognome);
    $('[name="telefono"]').val(data.telefono);
    $('[name="email"]').val(data.email);
    $('[name="cf"]').val(data.cf);
    $('[name="data_nascita"]').val(data.data_nascita);
    $('[name="comune"]').val(data.comune);
    $('[name="tipo_attivita"]').val(data.tipo_attivita);
    $('[name="note_anagrafica"]').val(data.note_anagrafica);
    $('[name="note_tipo_attivita"]').val(data.note_tipo_attivita);
  }

  function update(data)
    {
      $('[name="id_anagrafica_edit"]').val(data.id_anagrafica);
      $('[name="nome_edit"]').val(data.nome);
      $('[name="cognome_edit"]').val(data.cognome);
      $('[name="telefono_edit"]').val(data.telefono);
      $('[name="email_edit"]').val(data.email);
      $('[name="cf_edit"]').val(data.cf);
      $('[name="data_nascita"]').val(data.data_nascita);
      $('[name="comune_edit"]').val(data.comune);
      $('[name="tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(data.tipo_attivita);
      $('[name="note_anagrafica_edit"]').val(data.note_anagrafica);
      $('[name="note_tipo_attivita_edit"]').val(data.note_tipo_attivita);
    }

    $('.pagination').on('click','a',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var page_number = $(this).attr('data-ci-pagination-page');
      loadPagination(page_number);
    });

    loadPagination(0);

    // Load pagination
    function loadPagination(page_number){
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/load_record/'+page_number,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
           $('.pagination').html(response.pagination);
           show_costumer(response.result,response.row);
        }
      });
    }


    function show_costumer(result,sno){
      sno = Number(sno);
      $('#table tbody').empty();
      for(data in result){
          var cells = costumer_cells(result[data]);
          sno += 1;
          $('#table tbody').append(cells);
      }
      // $.ajax({
      //
      //     type  : 'ajax',
      //     url   : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/costumer_data",
      //     async : true,
      //     dataType : 'JSON',
      //     success : function(data)
      //       {
      //
      //         var html = '';
      //         var i;
      //         for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      //           {
      //             html += costumer_cells(data[i]);
      //           }
      //
      //         $('#show_costumer').html(html);
      //
      //       }
      //
      // });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function()
      {
        var search = $(this).val();

        if( search != "" )
          {
            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/search",
              data:'search='+$('#search_text').val(),
              dataType: "JSON",
              cache: false,
              success:function(data)
                {
                  var html = '';
                  var i;
                  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                    {
                      html += costumer_cells(data[i]);
                    }
                  $('#show_costumer').html(html);
                }
            });
          }
      });

    //Save product
    $('#btn_save').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/costumer/save",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : read(),
            success: function(data)
              {
                show_customer()
              }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Where I'm failing?

My link is `https://slpiraino.it/new/admin/clienti`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: show_customer is not defined` ... typo

Answer (score 1):

You are using the show_customer() function which is not defined that's why it's showing the error.

Please replace the show_customer() function with show_costumer() it will does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction but also with the correction, the process still no do the tricks...have you any other idea?

Comment: Any other hints?